# Spawn many subprocesses out to many different nodes on HPC using Joblib+Dask

Tags: python-2.7, cluster-computing, dask, slurm, joblib

I am trying to run a python program that, at one point, performs a lot (thousands) of embarrasingly parallel processes that are in the form of subprocess calls to other software.  I am running this on a slurm cluster across many different nodes, each of which has many cores.

I have used mpi4py, but there was a latency in the code that caused me to move towards working with joblib.  Joblib seemed like an easy way to parallelize these subprocess calls.  In order to run these across multiple CPUs (each CPU having multiple cores), I turned to dask as well, from googling around.

Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
from dask.distributed import Client,LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster()
print 'cluster', cluster
client = Client(cluster)
from sklearn.externals import joblib
...
def functionThatCallsSubprocessAndIsToBeParallelized(input):
    return subprocess.check_output("software call",stdin=input)

...
with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    res = joblib.Parallel(n_jobs=-2,verbose=1)(map(joblib.delayed(functionThatCallsSubprocessAndIsToBeParallelized),my_input))
```

I am expecting this to take my large number of inputs from `my_input` and return each result in an array to res.  I want to use all the nodes and their cores across what I have allocated in my sbatch file

```
#!/bin/bash
...
#SBATCH --nodes=2

srun -n 64 python parallel.py
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to replace the `LocalCluster` call (which uses only a single machine) with [dask-jobqueue](http://jobqueue.dask.org/en/latest/) or [dask-mpi](https://mpi.dask.org).  Each of those solutions will help you deploy Dask across many machines in an HPC environment.  After that Joblib+Dask should work more smoothly on those many machines.